# Differentiating clickable and downloadable links in Stack Overflow Blog post

Tags: feature-request, blog, accessibility, downloads

When accessing the Stack Overflow Blog post via mobile data, it becomes crucial to distinguish between clickable links and downloadable PDFs. The ability to identify and ignore PDF links can help streamline the browsing experience for users on limited mobile data plans. Specifically I'm referring this [Blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/11/27/are-remote-workers-more-productive-that-s-the-wrong-question).

By incorporating a visual indicator or a download icon for PDF links, mobile users can easily recognize and skip downloading files, saving both time and data resources. This improvement aims to cater to the needs of users who may want to conserve data or those who prefer not to download large files while on a mobile network.

Including a small, universally recognizable download icon adjacent to PDF links would be a practical solution. This unobtrusive visual cue serves as a quick reference, allowing users to make informed decisions about whether to engage with the link.

Comment: I didn't find any PDF in that blog post, but anyway, surely there's a setting that disable automatic download of files in mobile browsers. (i.e. when clicked should give you warning asking if you want to save the file)

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry search with "more productively" and "report".

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry [There ya go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CZ5Q.png)

Comment: For reference, that links to [this pdf](https://www.smf.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Social-Market-Foundation-Publication-Briefing-CAGE-4-Are-happy-workers-more-productive-281015.pdf#page=9).

Comment: [Relevant WebAIM guidance](https://webaim.org/techniques/hypertext/hypertext_links#non_html).

Comment: But every link has to be downloaded before being read. Regardless of whether it leads into a webpage or a PDF file. Whether the downloaded resource is displayed directly or saved to a file is up to the browser.

Comment: @user3840170 Past a certain point, you can only really say things like that if you're a browser developer, working on something other than Chromium, Firefoxium or Safarium. Many things that are "up to the browser" don't actually differ in practice, so users who need a different behaviour just have to lump it.

Comment: @user3840170 The amount of data doesn't matter really. Users should know what to expect when clicking on a link if it is not going to another HTML resource. Adding a simple (PDF) or (Video) after the link text is the simplest, most compatible way to share that information instead of relying on a screen reader or browser to detect it.

Comment: This is not some theoretical capability. I can open Firefox settings *right now* and choose if I want to use the browser’s built-in PDF viewer, automatically open an external one, or prompt to download PDF documents. Differentiating between “clickable” links and “downloadable” ones is nonsense: they are one and the same.